# Unity3D Resource.LoadAll adding types to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to find a way to have unity treat my .ai files as text files, so that Resource.Load and LoadAll will load them.  Is there a configuration change I can make to allow for this?  Right now it skips the .ai files completly.

Comment: [This](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/99740-Custom-asset-formats-can-someone-from-Unity-Technologies-support-help) might be related.  As far as I've ever been aware you can only load supported types w/ their API.  It's hacky but if you know the files can load as text, why not add a prepass that changes the file types or creates temp copies that are loaded by the Resources call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that the direct solution was not possible, or nobody seems to know it.  To get around this issue, we found that there is another folder in unity that allows for resources to be added and it is not compressed or mangled, and can be enumerated.

Use streaming assets, and the problem goes away.